# HTML5 client-side database location

Tags: database, html

I want to create a standalone todo list with HTML5.  Ideally, it would be a file that sits on a USB drive and could leverage a database (either embedded in the html file somewhat like  tiddlywiki) or would access another file.

I've read about Web SQL and SQL Lite, but it seems like they save the database information to a specific location on the local computer, and the user has no control over whether to place it elsewhere.  The app wouldn't really be portable if it saves a different instance for every machine upon which it's run.

Is there a solution to force the database to reside on the portable drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Client & Server Storage

**SQLite**

SQLite is a database engine that needs to be specifically installed on a machine or packaged with software. This type of technology is usually used on the server side with a server programming language like PHP. Therefore, I do not believe that server storage solution is for you.

**HTML5 Client Storage**

Meanwhile, Web SQL is an HTML5 feature for client storage. The databases are managed by the client (the browser) through JavaScript. The implementation of WebSQL is very similar to SQLite. Note that Firefox supports IndexedDB instead of WebSQL. Sadly, you can't force the browser to store the databases onto an external drive.

### The Solution

At this point, the most viable solution for you is to create an application that will be executed on the external drive. If you really want to use HTML5 you could go with [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-cross-platform-application-development/). It leverages the power of web technologies to create native cross-platform applications. From Titanium's [documentation](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/How+to+create+and+install+a+pre-populated+database) you can package a SQLite database with your application.